# What is TRANSFORM FOR TYPE?

Tags: functions, datatypes, postgresql-11

PostgreSQL 11 introduces `TRANSFORM FOR TYPE`, from these docs by HP, [PostgreSQL 11 New_Features](http://h50146.www5.hpe.com/products/software/oe/linux/mainstream/support/lcc/pdf/PostgreSQL_11_New_Features_beta1_en_20180525-1.pdf)

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION jsonb_plperl CASCADE ;
NOTICE: installing required extension "plperl"
CREATE EXTENSION

postgres=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fperl(val jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb
TRANSFORM FOR TYPE jsonb
LANGUAGE plperl
AS $$
 return $_[0] ;
$$ ;
CREATE FUNCTION

postgres=> SELECT fperl('{"1":1,"example": null}'::jsonb) ;
 fperl
---------------------------
{"1": 1, "example": null}
(1 row)
```

But it seems this would work the very same way if I remove `TRANSFORM FOR TYPE jsonb`

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/datatype-json.html#id-1.5.7.22.18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a totally useless example. I believe what `TRANSFORM FOR TYPE` is supposed to support is something like this,

```
postgres=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fperl(val jsonb)
RETURNS jsonb
TRANSFORM FOR TYPE jsonb
LANGUAGE plperl
AS $$
 return $_[0]->{foo};
$$ ;

SELECT fperl('{"foo":"bar"}'::jsonb) ;
```

You can see in the above that we actually see the jsonb object as a perl hash and can access the members.

`jsonb_plperl` is the new stuff here. [`CREATE TRANSFORM`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtransform.html) dates to PostgreSQL 9.5.